# How to write loops in gitlab-ci.yaml file?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, yaml, gitlab-ci

I am writing a GitLab-ci.yaml file for my application and in that I have to run the kubectl command to get all pods after I ran the command I got the names of the pods which I need but ow the thing is I have to run kubectl cp command and need to copy a file into all three pods but I don't know the way to perform this action.

If anyone knows the way to do this activity then please reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
job:
  script:
    - |
      for pod in $(kubectl get po -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name} -n your-namespace')
      do 
        kubectl cp $(pwd)/some-file.txt your-namespace/$pod:/
      done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
deploy:
  image:
    name: bitnami/kubectl:latest
    entrypoint: ['']
  script:
    - kubectl config get-contexts
    - kubectl config use-context path/to/agent/repository:agent-name
    - kubectl get pods
```

Comment: But I have to first store the output for kubectl get pods and then need to run a loop over all output pods. So, Can you please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Please refer https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#create-a-custom-cicd-variable-in-the-gitlab-ciyml-file You can use a variable and assign the output to the values.